# Generate random string to append in css/script links to avoid browser cache in jsp pages

Tags: html, css, jsp

Can anyone please tell how can i make random string for css/script files to avoid browser cache for jsp pages and that should run only if the css/script/sprite images has changed.if not its should take it from browser cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put a timestamp at the and of the file url, like this:

http://domain.com/style.css?t={current_timestamp}

However i don't recomend it. A good practce is to change the name of the file for its hash in every deploy. A script should change the name of the files and replace all the refrences to them.

Comment: good answer. The dev should make it part of his deployment to bump up the version of the script/css reference in his page

Answer (score 0):

A common way to do this in JavaScript is to use the current timestamp:

```
var ts = new Date().getTime();
```

it's not strictly 'random' but will avoid the caching issue that you described

Comment: agree on the method to do this however your solution means that the resource will always get reloaded from the server even when unecessary. The developer above, needs to make it part of his deployment to bump of the version of the script in the reference. There is no way to know that the resource has changed